# Create forms dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to implement an application that will be able to import WinForms files and use them in the same application. of course in order for this to work i will be storing each form i submit to my application in database. Is this possible, importing forms to an executable or if there is anyway to do it ?

Comment: Is it possible to create a worse title? I don't think so.

Comment: the question is only slightly better ... can you clarify what you mean by winforms files?  WinForms is a UI technology then you go onto to say the data from the form is in a db.  Are you looking to load pluggable UI components from a database?  Confused ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "of course" to storing forms in a database? What are you gonna do, design them in some editor, save all properties to XML, store it in the database and then read that in and reconstruct the form?

You have to tell what you are doing, a bit wider than storing forms. Do you want to reuse forms? Can't you stuff 'em in a DLL? Or do you want users to be able to change your form's layouts?